# How to create releases in Azure DevOps with a script

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a script that can create Release in Azure devops?
I need to create between 50 - 100 Release and I am looking for a suitable script.

Comment: Hi Nitro5; I can't give an Answer because your question is just too broad, but I recommend you look into [templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops) which will help if your many release pipelines have logic or tasks in common.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT
I am starting to work on this today, by your guide you sent 
I will keep reply if I will get more questions

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a script that can create Release in Azure devops?

You could use the REST API to create the release in Azure devops.

[Releases - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

POST [https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1](https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/release/releases?api-version=5.1)

But we need provide too much information in the Request Body, this will be a big project and error-prone. That also the reason why the document not provide a sample Request Body there.

To resolve this issue, usually we would use the REST API Definitions - Get to get the Response Body from the template pipeline:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get-release?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Then we just need to update the corresponding properties by modifying the Response Body.

Comment: you suggest to me to use : Releases - Create or Releases - Get Release?